# Progress Dialog not shown after exception

Tags: android

I am trying to do a file download using the below code. Everything works fine as far as the download is concerned. One problem I have is whenever there is a download failure, progress dialog does not show up. Am I missing anything obvious here? What is the cause for this?

Any help is much appreciated

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Downloading File");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();// Does not show during download exceptions- is it because the below download code fails abruptly?
    new NTLMTestData ().asyncNTLMTest("http://myurl/FileName.csv", this, getApplicationContext());
}

// The below call backs get fired from async    
@Override
public void onSuccess(String msg) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Add some logs to check, but probably the error is to fast and is calling onFailure before Android can render the progress dialog.

Comment: Why do you need mDialog.dismiss(); on failure? I think it only should be onsucess, but if there is an error the user itself will dismiss the dialog.

Comment: @jonathanrz I have checked puttng breakpoints, it hits mDialog.show(); So, possibly this can be an error which is related to the exception being thrown faster than before Android can render the progress dialog. - as you told

Answer (score 1):

Try this way instead

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
 try{
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Downloading File");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();
    new NTLMTestData ().asyncNTLMTest("http://myurl/FileName.csv", this, 
    getApplicationContext());
 } catch (Exception e){
    showError();
 }

}

private void showError(){
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mDialog.setTitle("Error")
    mDialog.setMessage("An error has occurred during download");
    mDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
     })
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();
}

// The below call backs get fired from async    
@Override
public void onSuccess(String msg) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
   //Leave blank
}
```

Hope it helps